# Filter array and form new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Right now I have data like the below:

```
[ 
        { 
           "integration_id":7,
           "campaign_id":4,
           "integration_name":"unbounce",
           "url_string":"23432fsaf",
           "created_at":"2019-12-23 21:05:45",
           "updated_at":"2019-12-23 21:05:45"
        },
        { 
           "integration_id":37,
           "campaign_id":4,
           "integration_name":"clickfunnels",
           "url_string":"yttzbe9rwd",
           "created_at":"2019-12-27 19:19:02",
           "updated_at":"2019-12-27 19:19:02"
        },
        { 
           "integration_id":47,
           "campaign_id":4,
           "integration_name":"instapage",
           "url_string":"vaqcjq8iy2",
           "created_at":"2019-12-29 16:52:01",
           "updated_at":"2019-12-29 16:52:01"
        }
]
```

But I want to transform this array into an array like below:

```
[
        { 
           "integration_name":"unbounce",
        },
        { 
           "integration_name":"clickfunnels",          
        },
        {  
           "integration_name":"instapage",            
        }
 ]
```

I want to keep the integration names but remove all other properties from the items. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what did you try? Show your code.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: `array.map(({integration_name}) => ({integration_name}));`

Comment: Please don't destroy the edits that people make to your question to make the code render well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over your data, and return only the `integration_name` Key / Value using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)

```js
const data = [{
    "integration_id": 7,
    "campaign_id": 4,
    "integration_name": "unbounce",
    "url_string": "23432fsaf",
    "created_at": "2019-12-23 21:05:45",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-23 21:05:45"
  },
  {
    "integration_id": 37,
    "campaign_id": 4,
    "integration_name": "clickfunnels",
    "url_string": "yttzbe9rwd",
    "created_at": "2019-12-27 19:19:02",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-27 19:19:02"
  },
  {
    "integration_id": 47,
    "campaign_id": 4,
    "integration_name": "instapage",
    "url_string": "vaqcjq8iy2",
    "created_at": "2019-12-29 16:52:01",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-29 16:52:01"
  }
];

let newArray = data.map(({integration_name}) => ({integration_name}));

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: You can change the lambda to this: `=> ({integration_id})`

Comment: Thank you; also made me realise I had wrote the wrong key initially

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

```js
let input = [{ "integration_id":7, "campaign_id":4, "integration_name":"unbounce", "url_string":"23432fsaf", "created_at":"2019-12-23 21:05:45", "updated_at":"2019-12-23 21:05:45" }, { "integration_id":37, "campaign_id":4, "integration_name":"clickfunnels", "url_string":"yttzbe9rwd", "created_at":"2019-12-27 19:19:02", "updated_at":"2019-12-27 19:19:02" }, { "integration_id":47, "campaign_id":4, "integration_name":"instapage", "url_string":"vaqcjq8iy2", "created_at":"2019-12-29 16:52:01", "updated_at":"2019-12-29 16:52:01" }]

let result = input.map(({integration_name}) => ({integration_name}));

console.log(result);
```